# Append XML to DOMNode in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I would like to append XML to DOMNode element, but I got the error : "Wrong Document Error".

Here is my code :

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xmlResources->asXml());
$orderNodeList = $dom->getElementsByTagName('order');

foreach ($orderNodeList as $orderNode) {
    $idAddressDelivery = $orderNode->getElementsByTagName('id_address_delivery')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $xmlToAppend = $this->getSpecificResource('addresses', $idAddressDelivery); //It returns a SimpleXMLElement

    $tmpNode = new \DOMDocument(); //I create a DOMDocument
    $tmpNode->loadXML($xmlToAppend->asXML()); //I fill it with XML

    $orderNode->appendChild($tmpNode); //I want to put the new XML inside the DOMNode, but it throws an error
}
```

I've searched on the web, but don't know how to make it, could you tell what's wrong please ?

Thank you for your help ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nodes are in a separate DOM. But you can only append nodes that are part of the same DOM. Here are two possibilities:

Import the nodes you loaded.

```
$target = new DOMDocument();
$target->loadXml("<one/>");

$source = new DOMDocument();
$source->loadXml("<two/>");

$target->documentElement->appendChild(
  $target->importNode($source->documentElement, TRUE)
);

echo $target->saveXml();
```

Load the XML into a fragment and append it.

```
$target = new DOMDocument();
$target->loadXml("<one/>");

$fragment = $target->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXml("<two/>");

$target->documentElement->appendChild($fragment);

echo $target->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<one><two/></one>
```

HINT: You might want to read about `DOMXpath::evaluate()`. It allows to fetch nodes using expressions. This is a lot more powerful then methods like `DOMNode::getElementsByTagName()`.

Comment: I just tried your solution first and it works, thank you for the reply !

Answer (score 1):

The error message

> *Wrong Document Error*

while operating with **DOMDocument** in PHP means, that one node is not part of the document you want it to operate with. A simple example of that is, that you have two different XML or HTML documents.

In your specific case the two documents are:

1. `$dom = new \DOMDocument();` (Line 1 in your example)
2. `$tmpNode = new \DOMDocument(); //I create a DOMDocument` (Line 9 in your example)

## The Solution

A way to make a node from different documents work together is to [*import nodes*](https://secure.php.net/manual/domdocument.importnode) into a document first and then operate with them (for example append them).

## An Example

Given two documents, *blue - docA* and *red - docB*:

```
$docA = new DomDocument();
$docA->loadXML('<blue/>');

$docB = new DomDocument();
$docB->loadXML('<red/>');
```

The document element *red* of *docB* can be appended to the document element *blue* of the former *docA* by importing the node:

```
$red = $docA->importNode($docB->documentElement, true);
$docA->documentElement->appendChild($red);
```

This will successfully append it to the first document which can be easily shown:

```
$docA->formatOutput = true;
$docA->save('php://output');
```

Which will give this output ([Demo](https://eval.in/389998)):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<blue>
  <red/>
</blue>
```

This hopefully shows you on how you can combine as many documents with each other like you want. Take note that you can't import full **DOMDocument**s into each other, *but* you can import the *document-element* which is the root element node of a document.

## Further Stackoverflow References

Similar questions have been asked before, this is a selective list of related Q&A material on site:

- [DOMElement cloning and appending: 'Wrong Document Error'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1759137/367456) (Nov 2009)
- [Copy DOMNodes from one DOMDocument to another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3091287/367456) (Jun 2010)

Answer (score 0):

You can't append a foreign node to your document. One way to do that is to create a new fragment in the first document with the xml string of the second document:

```
$fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML(/* put your xml content as a string here*/);

$orderNode->appendChild($fragment);
```